# Data annotation for model validation is not working as desired in mvc4

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `[Required]` for field validation. Scenario is, there are two check boxes and based on one selection, user has to add value in `textbox`. If it is empty then show validation error. Issue is, it validates it for first time, but shows validation message on both check box selection afterwards. What am I missing here?

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Flat Fee Amount")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter flat fee amount.")]
public string FlatFeeAmount { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 <div id="show-delivery-fee">
     <div>
         <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFee, "All", new {id = "All"}) %>
         <%= Html.Label("All", new {@for = "All"}) %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%-- BASED ON THIS CHECKBOX SELECTION DISPLAY VALIDATION MESSAGE--%>
         <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.DeliveryFee, "FlatFee", new {id = "FlatFee"}) %>
         <%= Html.Label("Flat Fee", new {@for = "FlatFee"}) %>
     </div>
     <div>
         <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount) %>
         <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount, new {maxlength = "5"}) %>
         <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FlatFeeAmount)%>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[RequiredAccessRights(AllowRightsOr = new[] { SystemRight.EditDelivery })]
[AuditActionFilter("Save store delivery. Store id: {model.StoreId.Value}")]
public ActionResult Delivery(StoreDeliveryModel model)
{
    if(this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            this.StoreManager.SaveDeliveryModel(model);
            model.Submitted = true;
        }
        catch (ValidationException exc)
        {
            this.ModelState.AddModelError("", exc.Message);
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want a conditional validation attribute - e.g a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIf]` or similar (or write your own)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I got my desired output if I use `RequiredIf` annotation in model.

Model:

```
[DisplayName("Flat Fee Amount")]
[RequiredIf("DeliveryFee", "FlatFee", ErrorMessage = "Please enter flat fee amount.")]
public string FlatFeeAmount { get; set; }
```